# odoo Inheriting Product Template using delegation, need to change default value for categ_id on form

Tags: inheritance, odoo, default-value, delegation, odoo-12

Inheriting by delegation product template. On a form view, I am placing the field *categ_id*. This is defaulting to 'All' and I would like it to point to a different category by default. I have tried the following,

`<field name="categ_id" domain="[('name', '=', 'Paper')]"/>`

which successfully filters the drop down list to just the category I want, but 'All' still shows as default.

Next I tried placing the context in the window action and the field with variations like

```
context="{'default_categ_id':%(pse.product_category_materials_paper)d}"
context="{'default_categ_id':'Paper'}"
context="{'default_categ_name':'Paper'}"
```

In the field *categ_id* definition, default=the _get_default_category_id is the issue from the debugger. It is bypassing the following line,

`return self._context.get('categ_id') or self._context.get('default_categ_id')`

Book says access to the inherited model are not made available in the new model? So I also tried overriding the function, and it did not work (is this even possible since this is delegation?)

Any pointers would be helpful. **Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the field categ id has default function running in the base. You can change the

```
categ_id = fields.Many2one(
    'product.category', 'Internal Category',
    change_default=True, default=_get_default_category_custom,
    required=True, help="Select category for the current product")
```

Please write the _get_default_category_custom function as you wish. That is to assign category as paper.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit more research, updating the default_get method is working.

```
@api.model
def default_get(self, vals):
   res = super(Paper, self).default_get(vals)
   categories = self.env['product.category'].search([('name', '=', 'Paper')])
   if categories:
       res.update({'categ_id': categories[0].id})
   return res
```

Still needs error checking if paper doesn't exist, though. Will point it back to product template 'All' default.